# XDebug something wrong on Windows 10 64 bit PHP 5.6.10

Tags: php, apache, wamp, xdebug, php-5.6

I've followed this tutorial [from this link](https://youtu.be/r5Aln5QjthM?t=12m18s), and when I check php version, I've got this error for this below.

I have updated php from 5.5.12 to 5.6.10.

```html
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.10>php -v
Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 15:58:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: First of all: do you have the file located at `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll`?

Comment: Not yet @sics. Ok I've moved that file

Comment: Same error on starting?

Comment: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.10>php -v
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.
The Zend Engine API version 220131226 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.

PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 15:58:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Comment: Seems like you mixed up your wamp installations. I strongly recommend you to not do it. Just install a clean version of wamp and enable the plugins you need.

Comment: Maybe yes @sics. But i've read about compilation and configuration xdebug at this link : https://xdebug.org/docs/faq. and I confuse for my problem.

Comment: I've written a step by step tutorial about Xdebug and XAMPP: https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. 
I would suggest check the xdebug Extension required for your configuration.
Paste your phpinfo() in

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

make sure you Ctrl-A and Ctrl-C so that all the configuration can be analyzed, that analysis would provide you summary and instruction on which xdebug version you need to use and what files you need to change.Then restart the webserver and after that run php -v